# composition of bijective map and expolential map of an operator

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $B(H)_{pi}$ be the set of all positive invertible operators on $H$,let $\phi$ be a bijective map from  $B(H)_{pi}$ to  $B(H)_{pi}$,$A\in  B(H)_{pi}$,can we have $\phi(e^A)=e^{\phi (A)}$?if $\phi$ is a $*$-homomorphism,the above conclusion holds.If $\phi$ does not preserve $*$-operation,is the conclusion also correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The map $\phi:B(H)_{pi}\to B(H)_{pi}$ given by $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is continuous and bijective, but
$$\phi(e^2)=e^{-2}\neq e^{1/2}=e^{\phi(2)}.$$

Comment: The following conclusion from a document:(Lem)Suppose $\psi :B(H)_s\to B(H)_s$ is a bijective map which preserves commutativity ($ab=ba$ iff $\psi(ab)=\psi(ba)$),then there exits an unitary operator or an antinuitary $U$ s.t. for any operator $S\in B(H)_s$,there exists a real-valued bdd Borel function $g_S$ on $\sigma(S)$ s.t $\psi(S)=Ug_S(S)U^*$.       Suppose $\phi$ is a bijective map on $B(H)_{pi}$ which preserves commutativity and we can construct a bijective map $f$ on $B(H)_S$ s.t $f(T)=log(\phi(e^T))$ and preserve commutativity,then $\phi(A)=Uf_A(A)U^*,\forall A\in B(H)_{ip}$(why?)